# Duplicate Tagging rows when columns are reversed pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the below dataset. There are 2 things that I'd like to do. I have already achieved the first step, which is to identify the duplicates when the columns are reversed and also when the third column is same.

Now, I'm trying to identify if there are duplicates when the main 2 columns are reversed and if the value of the 3rd column is different.

Input would look like:

```
TranscodeA,TranscodeB,Verfied
TC06396,TC02582,Yes
TC01232,TC05465,Yes
TC01474,TC02582,No
TC02582,TC06396,Yes
TC01591,TC03573,Yes
TC05465,TC01232,No
TC03573,TC01591,No
TC03573,TC01591,Maybe
TC03573,TC01591,Yaa
TC03573,TC01591,Nah
```

Output would look like:

| TranscodeA | TranscodeB | Verfied | Duplicate Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TC06396 | TC02582 | Yes | NA |
| TC01232 | TC05465 | Yes | DG1 |
| TC01474 | TC02582 | No | NA |
| TC01591 | TC03573 | Yes | DG2 |
| TC05465 | TC01232 | No | DG1 |
| TC03573 | TC01591 | No | DG2 |
| TC03573 | TC01591 | Maybe | DG2 |
| TC03573 | TC01591 | Yaa | DG2 |
| TC03573 | TC01591 | Nah | DG2 |

Step 1: Find duplicates for TranscodeA and TranscodeB when reversed and when other attributes are this was done using this line

`result = df.loc[pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df, axis=1), index=df.index).drop_duplicates().index]`

Step 2: Find duplicates when TranscodeA and TranscodeB are reversed and when Verified is different - is found, they should be grouped into one single duplicate group.

Please note - there can be many different values on the verified column, not just 2 or 3

This is where I need the help, I'm able to identify the duplicates but unable to group them into buckets.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the post has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

```
#helper DF with append column Verfied
df1 = (pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['TranscodeA','TranscodeB']], axis=1), index=df.index)
         .assign(Verfied=df['Verfied']))

#grouping by both columns
g = df1.groupby([0,1])['Verfied']

#test if for each group are all values different in Verfied column
m = g.transform('nunique').eq(g.transform('size')) & df1[[0,1]].duplicated(keep=False)

#create groups only for match requirements
df.loc[m, 'Duplicate Group'] = 'DG' + df1[m].groupby([0,1]).ngroup().add(1).astype(str)

print (df)
  TranscodeA TranscodeB Verfied Duplicate Group
0    TC06396    TC02582     Yes             NaN
1    TC01232    TC05465     Yes             DG1
2    TC01474    TC02582      No             NaN
3    TC02582    TC06396     Yes             NaN
4    TC01591    TC03573     Yes             DG2
5    TC05465    TC01232      No             DG1
6    TC03573    TC01591      No             DG2
7    TC03573    TC01591   Maybe             DG2
8    TC03573    TC01591     Yaa             DG2
9    TC03573    TC01591     Nah             DG2
```

Comment: Thanks for the above, it works but not when there is another row where Verified is "Maybe" for another row with values TC03575,TC01591,Maybe (any other value on Verifed, eg when there are more than 2 values in the same group... DG2) - apologies if I was unclear with the question

Comment: @get_unstuck - So need match rows with group length == 3? Is possible change question with all requirements?

Comment: @get_unstuck - because problem of groups with length 3 is not possible all 3 rows are reversed, only 2 of them. Third cannot be reversed.

Comment: basically, there can possibly be more than Yes, No, Maybe to the verified column ( needs to be dynamic )
answering your second question, the third column need not be reversed ... its only transcodeA and B that need to be reversed

Comment: updated the question mate, thanks for the answer, that worked well, just trying to understand that step by step now so that I can get what I'm after, but definitely a good start!

Comment: @get_unstuck - Super! answer was edited by your question. Basically only mask was changed.

Comment: thanks, that worked like charm... Took me sometime to find out the logic behind it - breaking it down to multiple lines worked! :)